# how to submit with a form data?

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data

I use a FormData() and I need to keep the behaviour of a regular form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post", action="/pageToGo">
    stuff...
</form>

<script>
    var regularForm = document.getElementById('myForm')

    var myFormData = new FormData(regularForm)
    myFormData.append(stuff...)

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('post', '/pageToGo')

    request.send(myFormData) // Do not change document.location.href
    regularForm.submit() // Do not include the happened stuff
</script>
```

I want to be redirected like if I submited in a regular form.

What can I do ? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Don't use FormData.

Append hidden input elements to the form instead. Then call its `submit()` method.

Comment: what if i want to add an input with a file ? because, It is not possible to set the file !

Answer (score 0):

create hidden input fields with name id and value you want to send

```
eg.<input name="say" id="say" value="Hi">
```

then see in your networks form data in devtool